# Terraform using IAM role assume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, terraform

I have been using access/secret keys with terraform to create/manage our infrastructure in AWS. However, I am trying to switch to using IAM role instead. I should be able to use a role in my account and assume the role in another account and should be able to run plan, apply etc to build infra in the other account. Any ideas, please suggest.

So far, I am testing with https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/, but for some reason, it is not working for me or the instructions are not clear to me.

Comment: Did you try using assume_role? If you are receiving any errors, share that also.

Comment: I did use assume role. Do I still need to use the access key/secret key for the user which will assume the role?

Answer (score 1):

Get the full ARN for the role you want to assume. In your provider config use the 'assume_role' block with the ARN: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html#assume_role

```
provider "aws"
  region = "<whatever region>"
  assume_role {
    role_arn     = "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:role/ROLE_NAME"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jpancoast. I figured that out after reading more on their documentation and it worked. Thanks for the post.

Answer (score 0):

We use a non-terraform script to setup our credentials using IAM role and assume role.(something like https://github.com/Integralist/Shell-Scripts/blob/master/aws-cli-assumerole.sh ) For using with okta, we use https://github.com/redventures/oktad

We get the tmp credentaials and token, save it in ~/.aws/credentials as respective dev/prod etc profile and then point our respective terraform provider configuration like this:

```
provider "aws" {
  region                  = "${var.region}"
  shared_credentials_file = "${pathexpand("~/.aws/credentials")}"
  profile                 = "${var.dev_profile}"
}
```